# ParseError: Unexpected character '�' when importing image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load a png image into my component from an images folder. However, I keep getting this error:

```
BROWSERIFY ERROR:

../../../src/js/images/001.png:1
�PNG
^
ParseError: Unexpected character '�'
```

I'm not sure where the ':1' is coming from after the file name. Nor the '�'.

This is the react starter i'm using if it matters:

https://github.com/joellongie/superCell

I'm importing like this:

```
import path from "../../images/001.png";
```

and using it like this:

```
<img src={path} style={imgStyle} />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does Browserify support Webpack-like loaders? If not, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you can load the PNG to a variable:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var img = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../../images/001.png');
```

You can then `base64` encode it and display it inline.

```
// Create new image element
var el = document.createElement('img');

// Encode PNG data as elements src, add headers
el.src = "data:image/png;base64, " + img.toString('base64');

// Append image to some element
document.getElementById("myContainer").appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score -2):

An image file is not a javascript module, you cannot `import` it. You want a simple

```
const path = "../../images/001.png";
```

where `path` is a string.

Comment: Very well could be using the webpack url-loader module which would process the image like a module.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, I don't think url-loader would process the image contents like a script module - because that's what currently happens.

Comment: nope, but in an isometric app where you're using node for server-side rendering, the url-loader module wouldn't be available and node would try to process it like a script, rendering that exact error.